# Question about proof extending measure to complete measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am looking through a proof in Folland, for Theorem 1.9, which states:

Suppose that $(X, M, \mu)$ is a measure space. Let $N = \{N' \in M : \mu(N') = 0\}$ and $M' = \{E \cup F : E \in M' \text{ and } F \subset N' \text{ for some } N' \in N\}$. Then $M'$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and there is a unique extension $\mu'$ of $\mu$ to a complete measure on $M'$.

Here is the proof as written: Since $M$ and $N$ are closed under countable unions, so is $M'$. If $E \cup F \in M'$, where $E \in M$ and $F \subset N' \in N$, we can assume that $E \cap N' = \emptyset$ (otherwise, replace $F$ and $N'$ by $F - E$ and $N'  - E$). Then $E \cup F = (E \cup N') \cap (N^c \cup F)$, so $(E \cup F)^c = (E \cup N')^c \cup (N' -F)$. But $(E \cup N)^c \in M$, and $N' - F \subset N'$, so that $(E \cup F)^c \in M'$. Thus $M'$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Here is my problem: I don't understand why $(E \cup N')^c \in M$. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: There is something to fix in your definition of set $N$. Do you mean $N = \{N' \in M : \mu(N^\prime) = 0\}$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yes, I have fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Then, I also think that $(E \cup N)^c$ should be replaced by $(E \cup N^\prime)^c$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net also correct, my apologies for all the issues!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**

You have $$(E \cup N^\prime)^c=E^c \cap (N^\prime)^c$$ and both set of the RHS belong to $M$.

Comment: isn't it $(E \cup N')^c = E^c \cap (N')^c$? And is it just a fact that $(N')^c \in M$? Is the complement of a null set always in the $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Ohhhh, never mind, I've figured it out, I think I was misreading the definition of $N$, I didn't realize we had restricted $N$ to the null sets in $M$.

Comment: You're write ... Typo on cup vs. cap. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $B\in M'$ then there is an $E\in M$ such that $B = E\cup F$ where $F\subset N'$ and $N'\in N$. Then \begin{align*}
X\setminus B &= X\cap B^c\\
&= X\cap (E\cup F)^c\\
&= X\cap ((E^c\cap N'^c\cap F^c)\cup (F^c\setminus N'^c))\\
&= X\cap ((E^c\cap N'^c)\cup (F^c \cap N'))\\
&= X\cap ((E\cup N')^c \cup (N'\setminus F))
\end{align*}
Since $(E\cup N)^c\in M$ and $(N'\setminus F)\subset N'\in M$ with $\mu(N') = 0$, hence, $B^c\in M'$